# external-ip show pending for service kourier in kourier-system

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, knative

I am working on knative(latest) and I am new to it. I am following the [knative document](https://knative.dev/docs/install/yaml-install/serving/install-serving-with-yaml/) for installation. Cluster is `EKS` with `kubernetes` version `1.25` and Im using `fargate`.

My end goal is deploy service on `eks` with `knative` and publish with `ALB`.

I am trying it with `helloworld` serivce like (lso tried with my ow custom service)

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: TARGET
              value: "World"
```

It create service in default namespace. the output of `kn service list` is [image]

Here I have tried to create the `targate group` with `IP address of pod` with container port and then added in `listner of ALB`. but targate goes in `unhealthy` state.

Now here as im new to `knative` and `kubernetes` Im not clear how can I use my `ALB` to access this service over internet.

but as in the `knative installation` document the output of below command

```
kubectl --namespace kourier-system get service kourier
```

shows `EXTERNAL-IP` as pending. based on my reading it means the external system is not ready to provisioned the IP. Im confuse here, based on the document no steps talked about ALB.

Another point I want to add, the output of `kubectl get csr` show all `csr` in pending state. so i manually approved them with `kubectl certificate approve CSR_NAME`

and then I tried to do `port-forwarding` and I was able to access my service on `localhost`.

I initially also tried with `istio` and then `virtualService` as well but didnt get there.
but after that I sicked with `kourier` and done some experiments around it with no luck.